# How to use PhotoLibrary without jailbreak

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, photolibrary

This is nice thing you have done. Could you please explain: How to use PhotoLibrary's CameraController without jailbreak. Actually I 've downloaded class-dump and tried dumping PhotoLibrary but did not work out well. It is giving:

```
/*
 *     Generated by class-dump 3.1.2.
 *
 *     class-dump is Copyright (C) 1997-1998, 2000-2001, 2004-2007 by Steve Nygard.
 */
```

This file does not contain any Objective-C runtime information.

So, I wanted to know how to dump it and use it in xcode.

Answer (score 0):

a) You can't use PhotoLibrary directly because it's not part of the iPhone SDK. That's presumably what you mean by "without jailbreak"

b) Who's Mark and what has he done?

Comment: Mark must be a coder active here on StackOverflow who hacked the iPhone so you could PhotoLibrary on it without jailbreaking it.

Answer (score 0):

`PhotoLibrary` is a C framework (contains no ObjC code) so class-dump gives nothing. (And no, you can't use PL in SDK-compliant code.)